# How to read objects in an inputstream from Java server using objective-c

Tags: objective-c, ios, applet, httprequest

I'm doing an ipad app. Actually, I'm converting a java applet application to the ipad version. I've got a lot of problems.

In the original java applet code, there are some http POST request, and it will receive some data from the java server.

```
        httpCon=(HttpURLConnection) cmdURL.openConnection();
        httpCon.setRequestMethod("POST");
        httpCon.addRequestProperty("cmd", cmd);
        httpCon.addRequestProperty("arg", arg);
        httpCon.setDoInput(true);
```

and then, receive data:

```
        inputStream=httpCon.getInputStream();
        ObjectInputStream ois=new ObjectInputStream(inputStream);
        Document doc=(Document)ois.readObject();
        rData[2]=doc;
```

now, I want to do the same thing using objective-c:

```
NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://192.168.1.4:801/cmd"];
NSMutableURLRequest * request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",cmd] forHTTPHeaderField:@"cmd"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",arg] forHTTPHeaderField:@"arg"];

[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

`_responseData` is the data received:

```
    - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response{
        _responseData = [NSMutableData data];}

    - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
        [_responseData appendData:data];
    }
```

So, what should I do next? And there is a `Document` class in the java applet code, is there any similar class in the objective-c?

=======UPDATE=======

the java server returns the `xml` as the `Document` instance. Can I use the `_responseData` as an `xml` file directly? Or I have to do additional steps before dealing with the `_responseData`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cant use java object streams in objC. It is meant to send **java object**

... well in thoery you could IF you reverse engineered the protocol the objectStream uses but that's a lot of work and a maintenance hell (I guess) - 
I would look into Using a common exchange format.. **json or xml maybe!**

after your edit:
I dont know the xml the objectstream sends but in theory you can just parse it and setup a custom objC class with it.
I also dont know what the Document class is or does or where its from so I cant say if there's an equivalent in Java. I tend towards no.

Comment: well that's what I'm afraid of. thanks anyway

Comment: on java side write to JSON and objC parse it from JSON. it shouldnt be that difficult. ObjC as well as Java have good JSON Support :)

Comment: so I need to modify the server side code. I'll have a try. cheers

Comment: plz see my update. may I just use `_responseData` as an `xml` file?